# Why is the diagonal line in ROC space called the random guess?

Tags: machine-learning, roc

all. I'm a student who studies machine learning.

When I found the wiki over the ROC(Reciever Operation Characteristic), I had one question. 
According to the wiki, ROC space has a diagonal line and the line is called random guess.

I understand the meaning of random guess intuitively about some certain cases,
but I don't accept the concept in others.

For example, suppose the two situations like the below table.

| Situation 1 | Condition Positive | Condition Negative |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Predicted Positive** | 77 | 77 | 154 |
| **Predicted Negative** | 23 | 23 | 46 |
|  | 100 | 100 | 200 |

| Situation 2 | Condition Positive | Condition Negative |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Predicted Positive** | 20 | 60 | 80 |
| **Predicted Negative** | 80 | 240 | 320 |
|  | 100 | 300 | 400 |

The first situation and the second situation respond to the point (0.77, 0.77) and (0.2, 0.2) respectively. 
And the points lie on the diagonal line in the ROC space.

In the first case, precision and accuracy are both 0.5. So I can accept the meaning of random guess intuitively.
But in the second case, precision and accuracy are not both 0.5.

Nonetheless, why can we also call the second case that lies on the diagonal line a random guess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second case, accuracy is 260/400 = 0.65, but *balanced accuracy*, defined as (TPR + TNR)/2 is still 0.5.

[This question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/31872/10777)'s comments and answers might also be helpful? I.e. on the difference between one point on the line, and what the whole line represents.